# Bitly shorten URL - getting status as WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, bitly

I am trying to generate short link Using bitly but getting "**Status = WaitingForActivation**"

```
public async Task<string> GetShortUrl(string url)
{
    var myAccessToken = "Token";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {myAccessToken}");

    var content = new
    {
        long_url = url
    };
    //HTTP POST
    var resp = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten", content);
    var link = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return link;
}
```

```html
[HttpGet("redirectUser/{PlanId}")]
        [ValidateModelState]
        public async Task<IActionResult> sendNotification(Guid PlanId)
        {
             var surveylink = "https://chats.landbot.io";
             // getting Status = WaitingForActivation
             var shortLink = GetShortUrl(surveylink); 
            }
        }
```

I am getting Status = WaitingForActivation at

```html
var shortLink = GetShortUrl(surveylink);
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this status?

Comment: in another method where I am calling this GetShortUrl function.

Comment: Why do you keep treating your code as HTML when it isn't?

Comment: The issue is clearly that you're not awaiting `GetShortUrl`...

Comment: @Llama, Yes you are right. I await GetShortUrl and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple reason for this issue is that when the below given love is being executed :-

```
var resp = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten", content);
```

It is causing the code to move to the next line without completing the current part. So, the next line :-

```
var link = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

is unable to execute properly as a result.

What you can do to solve this issue is create a waiting period till some response is returned. Once a response is returned, then move to the next line and then return the link.

Comment: could you please tell me how I can create a waiting period till the response is returned?

Comment: Try adding "resp.wait();" before declaring the link variable